# jQuery-File-Upload: Image preview not being generated for all images

Tags: jquery-file-upload, blueimp

For most images jQuery-File-Upload is displaying a preview image. However, for some large images (14MB) no preview is being displayed. Why is this happening and is there anyway to fix this? Unfortunately I am not seeing any errors on my web dev console when this happens so I have no idea how to debug this issue.

Here is a link to an [example image](http://fotonin.com/data_images/out/24/944648-nature.jpg) that will not display a preview for me.

Answer (score 3):

This helps me in same situation:

in file

> jquery.fileupload-image.js

change parameter

> loadImageMaxFileSize: 40000000 /40MB